VolumeReadOps spikes consume credits on AWS EBS with mysql doing almost nothing
Since a couple of days I am noticing a problem with mysql on AWS. This particular server has been in production for 3 years without any prior issues.
Recently, a spiking read activity from mysql is consuming BurstBalance fast. I am not an expert in Mysql or InnoDb configuration and I am running with the default configuration which worked well for a long time.
I believe it might be somehow related to swapping or caching since VolumeWrite operations have been consistently low. Mysql queues are empty and the load is very limited. The problem seem to come entirely from reading activity not related to queries or traffic.
here is a picture from the AWS dashboard https://ibb.co/XC18pzN
I have reduced the database by eliminating data that could be eliminated. Also tried moving the service on a different AWS instance hoping that it could be an instance related problem.
I would much appreciate any help about how to address this.
Thank you

You need a DBA not a programmer to take a look at this problem. Please delete your question from here and ask it on the dba sister site of SO.
